# Javascript Cookies when are active?

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie

I would like to ask a question. When i set a javascript cookie for example:

`document.cookie="username=John; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2017 12:00:00 UTC";`

is it active in real time or we must wait until user refresh the website page or revisit it.

Actually i am asking because i want to include in my log in system a piece of code that will track how many times the user accept the form.

For security reasons if the user accept the form multiple times in less than 5 minutes then to track the user ip and disable user to accept the log in form for the next 2 hours.

It's important to inform you that the form post is via ajax request so the page does not refresh

Comment: It has nothing to do with “refreshing” the website – the only thing that matters, is that a request is send to the server after the cookie was set.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah is true but if we retrieve info about counting how many times tried a user and user reach the limit we can disable form from sending the request to the server. So when we set the cookie can we get it without refresh page, in real time?

Comment: If you want to prevent the form from sending the data, you need to do that client-side anyway. But you will need to check this on the server, too – because I can send any data I like to your site, and I don’t even have to use a “browser” to do that.

Comment: Perhaps using sessions to begin with (instead of implementing your own cookie solution) would make more sense though.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your comments. I will try to using sessions instead